# How to fetch a button X and Y coordinate if button is added programatically in linear layout

Tags: java, android

I have two linear layout in the screen. one is containing 5 buttons with each button click i need to add same button to the other linear layout and fetch its X and Y coordinate for animation. How can i exactly fetch X and Y coordinate?

```
    top = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toplinear);
    bottom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom);
    buttonText = new ArrayList<>();

     for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                buttonText.add(i + "");
            }
    for(String key : buttonText){
                Button button  = new Button(this);
                button.setText(key);
                button.setTag(Integer.parseInt(key));
                button.setLayoutParams(vv);
                setBottomButtonClick(button);
                bottom.addView(button);

            }

 public void setBottomButtonClick(final Button button){

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams vv = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(button.getX() +" clickedd button "+button.getY());

                Button b = new Button(Main2Activity.this);
                b.setText(((Button)v).getText());
                b.setLayoutParams(vv);
                top.addView(b);
                // fetch button b X and Y coordinate so that we can animate button 

            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: `b.getX();` `b.getY();`

Comment: its always give 0 and 0 . If i use linearlayout.getChildAt its also coming 0 and 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button b = new Button(Main2Activity.this);
b.setText(((Button)v).getText());
b.setLayoutParams(vv);
top.addView(b);
//try this
b.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                float x = b.getX();
                float y = b.getY();
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes i got the x and y but animation                         v.animate().x(x).y(y).setDuration(1000); is happening within bottom linear layout not on top linear layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

```
View.getX()
View.getY()
```

These values are related to View itself. If you want exact coordinates relative to the parent,
then you could use

```
View.getLeft()[It will give X position from the left] 
View.getTop() [It will give Y position from the top]
```

For your case,

```
b.getLeft()
b.getTop()
```

Comment: i m getting x and y as per screen but i m not able to animate outside bottom linear layout. animation should be like from button slide up from bottom linear layout to top linear layout. But right now its getting clipped not moving outside the bottom linear layout

Comment: Upto my knowledge you cannot animate child views out of parent view's boundaries. You can use single RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout instead of multiple(nested) LinearLayouts.